# Using Access vba to Import all tables from unopenable mdb file

Tags: vba

I have an issue.

Pretty much, I have an mdb file that cannot be opened (user account does not have permission) , but it can be imported into Access 2010.  I need to automate this to open any number of files (assuming mdb files for now).

Apparently, DoCmd.TransferDatabase does not allow me to ignore the source table name (despite being optional in api).  There is no way for me to know what these tables are before I try to import the file.

I need a way to automatic this process while bypassing the user account error.

Finally

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", theFile, acTable

That is my attempt, it gets a 3011 error

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I gave up using TransferDatabase to get all the tables and used other means to do so.  It seems that opening the workbook via vba bypassed the security error I was getting trying to open it directly.

This is the code:

```
Private Function importTables(theFile As Variant)
Dim db As Database
Dim td As TableDef
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(theFile, True)

For Each td In db.TableDefs
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(td.Name, 4) <> "~TMP" Then

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", theFile, acTable, _
        td.Name, td.Name
    End If
Next
db.Close
```

End Function